# Plotting a Normal Distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, normal-distribution, probability-density, probability-distribution

Is this a good way of plotting a Normal Distribution? On occasion, I get a pdf value (`pdf_x`) which is greater than 1.

```
% thresh_strain contains a Normally Distributed set of numbers
[mu_j,sigma_j] = normfit(thresh_strain);   
x=linspace(mu_j-4*sigma_j,mu_j+4*sigma_j,200);   
pdf_x = 1/sqrt(2*pi)/sigma_j*exp(-(x-mu_j).^2/(2*sigma_j^2));   
plot(x,pdf_x);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of a pdf is 1, at any point the values can be higher. Your plot is corect.

Answer (score 0):

As @[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2732801/daniel) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22671867/8239061), with continuous random variables the [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is a derivative of a probability (or a measure of intensity) so it can be greater than one. The [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is a probability and must always be on [0, 1].

As an example, take the distributions marked below. The area under each curve is 1 (they are valid distributions) yet the density can be above 1.

[image: Example w/ PDFs above 1]

Related StackExchange posts: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720053/how-can-a-probability-density-function-pdf-be-greater-than-1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105455/how-can-a-probability-density-be-greater-than-one-and-integrate-to-one)